# Delayed Phase Transition at Condensation of a Gas?

Tags: thermodynamics

It is known that super heated liquids do exist, eg. when purified water is carefully heated above its boiling point. However I've never heard of subcooled gas having a temperature below its saturation temperature. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've never heard of subcooled gas having a temperature below its saturation temperature.

There are plenty of instances of subcooled gases. Cloud nucleation is a prominent example. Cloud chambers for radioactive particle tracking also rely on subcooled gases (or supersaturated solutions of a liquid dissolved in a gas, which is probably a slightly more precise way to put it).

Comment: Yes, right. Oversaturation is possible with gas-vapour mixture when condensation nuclei are missing. But is there anything similar with pure gas as well?